# How to use state to update the value of variable in the button value property?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a Figma Plugin and using React.js, this is my first time trying to code, I have a great HTML/CSS knowledge but JS not so much.

Basically I want that the newCornerRadius variable to return the int inside the value property inside the button tag that it is being clicked. But right now I'm only getting the value of the first button, even if I click on the other buttons like 8, 16,...

[Figma plugin interface and inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxFdz.png)

this is my ui.tsx code

```html
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './ui.css'

declare function require(path: string): any

class App extends React.Component {

  cornerRadiusValues = [4, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48];
  
  cornerRadiusButtons = this.cornerRadiusValues.map((cornerRadiusValue, index) =>
  <button key={index} value={cornerRadiusValue} id="cornerRadiusValue" onClick={() => this.setAttibute()}>{cornerRadiusValue}</button>
  );

  setAttibute = () => {
    const newCornerRadius = parseInt((document.getElementById('cornerRadiusValue') as HTMLInputElement).value);
    parent.postMessage({ pluginMessage: {type:'set-corner-radius-attribute',newCornerRadius}}, '*');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.cornerRadiusButtons}
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-page'))
```

```html
figma.showUI(__html__)

figma.ui.onmessage = msg => {
  if (msg.type === 'set-corner-radius-attribute') {

    for(const node of figma.currentPage.selection) {
      if ("cornerRadius" in node) {
        node.cornerRadius = msg.newCornerRadius;
      } else {
        console.log('corner radius not available')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think I need to use useState() but I simply can't figure out where and how!

Thanks in advance folks, been using Stack Overflow for almost a decade now, I'm happy to finally join the JS part of it.

Answer (score 0):

for access to the value of the button, you can pass the value into the onClick method

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './ui.css'

declare function require(path: string): any

class App extends React.Component {
state={currentValue:''}
  cornerRadiusValues = [4, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48];
  
  cornerRadiusButtons = this.cornerRadiusValues.map((cornerRadiusValue, index) =>
  <button key={index} value={cornerRadiusValue} id="cornerRadiusValue" 
onClick={() => this.setAttibute(cornerRadiusValue)}>{cornerRadiusValue}</button>
  );

  setAttibute = (value) => {
    this.setState({
...this.state,
currentValue:value
})
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.cornerRadiusButtons}
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-page'))
```

> and you can access the value of state inside of component with this command `this.state.currentValue`

> Copy an object to another one

```js
var firstObject = {
    key1 : 'value1',
    key2 : 'value2'
};

var secondObject = {
    ...firstObject,
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about what the '...this.state' does, could you clarify? Thanks!!!!

Comment: maybe here is not applicable but if you have many properties and you want to change one of them you must copy the other property to the new object, it is the syntax of new object definition `newobject={...oldObject,Prop1:value}. you can ignore it here

Comment: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/